# How to optimise this MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT k.strNaam
FROM klant AS k
INNER JOIN project AS p ON p.iKlantID = k.iKlantID
LEFT JOIN klant_factuurregels AS kfr ON kfr.iJobID = p.iProjectID
WHERE p.iFactuurID =  '49'
OR kfr.iFactuurID =  '49'
```

This query takes more than 0.5 seconds to load, but I am using it in a while loop so that's very inefficient.

Thanks in advance

**Edit** the MySQL query with the `EXPLAIN` command prepended:

```
id  | select_type   | table | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len           | ref                       | rows    | Extra
1     SIMPLE          p       ALL     iKlantID        NULL        NULL                NULL                        18848  
1     SIMPLE          k       eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY     8                   projecten.p.iKlantID        1  
1     SIMPLE          kfr     ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL                NULL                        18        Using where
```

Comment: Why are you using it inside a loop? Can't you refactor it somehow so you get all the data you need in one query?

Comment: Well, I am showing all invoices made, and per invoice I need to get the customers name (invoice = factuur and customer = klant). If this code cannot be optimised, I will have todo some other tricks then.

Comment: What does the `EXPLAIN SELECT` say? (run the query with `EXPLAIN` prepended)

Comment: @Piskvor please have a look at [this image](http://i53.tinypic.com/2ir0t9u.png)

Comment: @Devator: Could you edit it into your question, as plaintext? Note that the query doesn't use any index at all for tables `p` or `kfr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if this one won't be faster... because of the or condition in the where clause, index cannot be used to resolve the WHERE. But the worst part is that the iKlantID index was not used to resolve the join.

```
SELECT k.strNaam
FROM klant AS k
INNER JOIN project AS p ON p.iKlantID = k.iKlantID
LEFT JOIN klant_factuurregels AS kfr ON kfr.iJobID = p.iProjectID
WHERE p.iFactuurID =  '49'
UNION 
SELECT k.strNaam
FROM klant AS k
INNER JOIN project AS p ON p.iKlantID = k.iKlantID
LEFT JOIN klant_factuurregels AS kfr ON kfr.iJobID = p.iProjectID
WHERE kfr.iFactuurID =  '49'
```

Comment: Thank you. This query takes 0.0004 seconds to load instead of 0.5 seconds!

Comment: And why the left join when you never use the values?

Comment: @Johan it does when you have OR between different field (not different values). Ok, in newer versions of MySQL, MySQL may use index_merge (if there Which is still not as fast as usual index. But explain show that no index is used.

Comment: @symcbean I do use the values, but they are not always available.

Answer (score 1):

**Speed issues**
Put indexes on all fields involved in the joins.
And on `iFactuurID`.

**Loops and SQL don't mix**
Well they do, but slowness will be the result.

Instead try code like this.

```
$array = (10,11,12,13,49);
//if this comes from outside you need to sanitize these values 
//using PDO or mysql_real_escape_string
$in = "'".implode("','",$array)."'"; 
$sql = "SELECT k.strNaam
        FROM klant AS k
        INNER JOIN project AS p ON p.iKlantID = k.iKlantID
        LEFT JOIN klant_factuurregels AS kfr ON kfr.iJobID = p.iProjectID
        WHERE p.iFactuurID IN ($in)
        OR kfr.iFactuurID IN ($in) ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
   //do stuff
}
```

If the values are consecutive, it's much faster to use

```
WHERE p.iFactuur BETWEEN '$lowvalue' AND '$highvalue'
```

Always let SQL do the heavy lifting in loops.

Comment: Normally yes, but I am working in an already developed database structure, and it's not very efficient... at all.

Comment: @devator, adding indexes to the database should not create too many problems, make a copy of the database, add indexes and see what happens.

Comment: I did, I indexed them but not a noteable difference.